# Change zsh prompt to only two folders

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using the `oh-my-zsh` theme `jtriley`. The theme code, reproduced below, displays the entire directory path:

```
PROMPT="%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}%T%{$fg_bold[green]%} %{$fg_bold[green]%}%d
%{$fg_bold[yellow]%}%% %{$reset_color%}"
```

I know that there are ways to change the displayed directories, using the `prompt_dir()` function,  following instructions like [these](https://shandou.medium.com/how-to-shorten-zsh-prompt-oh-my-zsh-14185f3e7ab7). However, when I insert this below the code above, I do not get a change.

How can I alter a theme file where the only code in it is the prompt, and its colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular use case, you can just replace `%d` with `%2d` in the first line.

However, if you want to do something fancier, you can replace it with `\$(prompt_dir)` instead, and set the PROMPT_SUBST option. The backslash is important, since that makes it so the function is re-evaluated each time the prompt is displayed, rather than just when `$PROMPT` is assigned.

Comment: Thanks, the first part does what I need. What exactly do you mean with the 2nd paragraph? I'm not following.

Comment: You can use standard command substitutions like `$(git status)` inside your prompt. However, since you're using double quotes around the prompt string, that would evaluate the command when your .zshrc is loaded, which probably isn't what you want. I think you can disregard the part about PROMPT_SUBST, since oh-my-zsh sets that by default. For example, [https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/themes/gallifrey.zsh-theme](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/themes/gallifrey.zsh-theme) is a small theme that does this.